# Linux server two network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I am configuring a local server which comes with two network interfaces (enp3s0f0 and enp3s0f1). I like to have both interfaces on the same subnet (192.168.178.*) with different IP-addresses (192.168.178.4|192.168.178.5), (is it possible to have the same address mapping on both devices?) to archive the following:

- The server should be reachable with both 1GBit interfaces running 2 adresses but the same domain. This way I thought I could split the connections DNS-RR and provide 2GBit capablities.
- The server is configured as KVM host and should be able to bridge both interfaces to the clients. This could allow a client to benefit from the 2GBit connection as well.

This is my current /etc/network/interfaces of the host

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: br0
auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
  address   192.168.178.4
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   192.168.178.1
  bridge_ports   enp3s0f0
  bridge_stp     off
  bridge_fd      0
  bridge_maxwait 0

  up route add -host 192.168.178.6 dev br0

# device: br1
auto  br1
iface br1 inet static
  address   192.168.178.5
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   192.168.178.1
  bridge_ports   enp3s0f1
  bridge_stp     off
  bridge_fd      0
  bridge_maxwait 0

  up route add -host 192.168.178.7 dev br1
```

The host is now kind of reachable via both addresses (.4/.5), but arp -a showed they have the same mac:

```
? (192.168.178.4) at c:c4:7a:de:e5:55 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.178.5) at c:c4:7a:de:e5:55 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

My hosts ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:de:e5:54  
          inet Adresse:192.168.178.4  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ec4:7aff:fede:e554/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:19698 Fehler:0 Verloren:380 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:8 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:2717375 (2.7 MB)  TX-Bytes:648 (648.0 B)

br1       Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:de:e5:55  
          inet Adresse:192.168.178.5  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ec4:7aff:fede:e555/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:21054 Fehler:0 Verloren:380 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:998 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:2814729 (2.8 MB)  TX-Bytes:246287 (246.2 KB)

enp3s0f0  Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:de:e5:54  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ec4:7aff:fede:e554/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:28517 Fehler:0 Verloren:38 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:24 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:5224971 (5.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:1944 (1.9 KB)

enp3s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 0c:c4:7a:de:e5:55  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ec4:7aff:fede:e555/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:30087 Fehler:0 Verloren:38 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1282 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:5363437 (5.3 MB)  TX-Bytes:350457 (350.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:163 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:163 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX-Bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)  TX-Bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 52:54:00:0b:76:e9  
          inet Adresse:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Is this the correct way to have maximum network performance? Or is there any smarter way to solve this?

Comment: Could interface bonding be a good idea to simplify things?

http://louwrentius.com/achieving-450-mbs-network-file-transfers-using-linux-bonding.html

Answer (score 0):

In general it is possible, but what you are experiencing right now with the ARP table is known as the *arp flux*.
You should be able to overcome this by setting the parameters as follows in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, depending on your distribution and release.

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2
```

These settings will only apply after a reboot, but you can `echo` these values into `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/<interface>/[arp_ignore|arp_announce]`. You also have to clear your arp cache afterwards and switches might also have a wrong arp table. So be patient.

The better approach would be to configure a bonding like @christian667 already mentioned. On linux you configure e.g. *balanced-alb* which does not need switch support.
If your switch supports bonding, use that one instead.

Bonding will make it easier for you and others.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I will go the bonding way. I don't think our switches support bonding so I try it the linux way. My /etc/network/interfaces would look like:

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.178.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.178.0
    broadcast 192.168.178.255
    gateway 192.168.178.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
    bond-slaves enp3s0f0 enp3s0f1
    bond-mode 0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-updelay 200
    bond-downdelay 200
```

Update: This is my final /etc/network/interface,
is this correct or am I missing something?

```
# Loopback device: 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
# 0 - balance-rr
# 6 - balance-alb
# 4 - 802.3ad
bond-mode 6
bond-miimon 100
bond-updelay 200
bond-downdelay 200
bond-slaves none

auto enp3s0f0
iface enp3s0f0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp3s0f1
iface enp3s0f1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.178.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.178.255
gateway 192.168.178.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
bridge_ports bond0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0

up route add -host 192.168.178.6 dev br0
up route add -host 192.168.178.7 dev br0
up route add -host 192.168.178.8 dev br0
up route add -host 192.168.178.9 dev br0
up route add -host 192.168.178.10 dev br0
```

Update 2: I tried several load balancing modes as I try to reach 2 GBit/s overall performance and finally I am using mode 6 (adaptive load balancing). The KVM root server is now reachable with 2 GBit/s (1 GBit/s for each office), but the KVM clients only have 1 GBit/s. I tested both with iperf.

Do I have to make any further adjustments to improve the clients performance?

Comment: Mode 0 bonding requires support on the switch.  You could use a different mode if your switch lacks support but you won't get a 2Gbps connection  i.e. no single transfer will achieve > 1Gbps transfer rate.  However, your 1Gbps bond will be twice as hard to saturate.  The best reference is here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: @BrandonXavier I tried mode 0 and archived from two different devices via iperf ~2GBit (870MBit/s), so I think my switch supports  Bonding-Mode-RR?
Does it help to increase the tcp window size for more speed? Our network is quite new

Comment: Poor wording in my comment - modes *other* than 0 (in case you needed to use one) won't achieve the aggregated bandwidth.

Comment: Also, in this scenario changing the tcp window is unlikely to have any significant positive effect.  You're being limited by the speed of the wire - not by buffers or protocol overhead.